# ldconfig creating bad symlink

Tags: linux, bacula

I have installed Bacula 7.4.4 on an openSUSE Leap 42.3 System from the repository https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home%3AXimi1970%3AopenSUSE%3AExtra/bacula recommended on https://software.opensuse.org/package/bacula.
Those packages use openSUSE's alternatives mechanism to configure the
DMBS to use for the catalog - in my case, MySQL. Unfortunately, the
package is a bit buggy. After installation of the bacula-director
and bacula-mysql packages, the symlinks for the libbaccats library in
/usr/lib64 look like this:

```
libbaccats.so -> /etc/alternatives/libbaccats.so
libbaccats-mysql.so -> libbaccats-mysql-7.4.4.so
libbaccats-stub.so -> libbaccats-7.4.4.so
libbaccats-7.4.4.so -> libbaccats-stub-7.4.4.so
```

The last two are obviously nonsense and cause any attempts to run the
director or the dbcheck utility to fail with the error message:

> Fatal error: Please replace this null libbaccats library with a proper
>   one.

This is of course easily fixed by issuing the commands:

```
ln -sf libbaccats-stub-7.4.4.so libbaccats-stub.so
ln -sf /etc/alternatives/libbaccats-7.4.4.so libbaccats-7.4.4.so
```

to produce the desired result:

```
libbaccats.so -> /etc/alternatives/libbaccats.so
libbaccats-7.4.4.so -> /etc/alternatives/libbaccats-7.4.4.so
libbaccats-mysql.so -> libbaccats-mysql-7.4.4.so
libbaccats-stub.so -> libbaccats-stub-7.4.4.so
```

which allows the symlinks in /etc/alternatives:

```
libbaccats.so -> /usr/lib64/libbaccats-mysql.so
libbaccats-7.4.4.so -> /usr/lib64/libbaccats-mysql-7.4.4.so
```

to correctly direct libbaccats references to the MySQL variant.

However, each time the `ldconfig(8)` command is run it resets the /usr/lib64/libbaccats-7.4.4.so symlink to point to libbaccats-stub-7.4.4.so again, breaking Bacula. Since `ldconfig` is run automatically by the system on various occasions this is pretty annoying.

The same problem exists with Bacula 9.0.6 from the repository https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/cristyde/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/.

How can I fix `ldconfig`'s idea where that symlink should point?

Comment: Did you try to symlink the files into `/usr/local/lib64`? That palce is intended for doing stuff without affecting the standard paths and should be skipped by `ldconfig`.

Comment: No, I didn't try anything involving `/usr/local`. What exactly do you propose? Which symlinks should I place in `/usr/local/lib64`? Should I remove any or all of the symlinks in `/usr/lib64`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my research, the (mis-)behaviour of `ldconfig` is triggered by the *content* of the file `libbaccats-stub-9.0.6.so`, specifically its `SONAME` field:

```
ts@xenon:~> objdump -p /usr/lib64/libbaccats-stub-9.0.6.so

/usr/lib64/libbaccats-stub-9.0.6.so:     file format elf64-x86-64
[...]
Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  SONAME               libbaccats-9.0.6.so
```

Apparently that header tells `ldconfig` to create a symlink with that name.

Proof: If I rename `libbaccats-stub-9.0.6.so` to `libbaccats-stub-9.0.6.so.BAD` then `ldconfig` duly creates a symlink

```
libbaccats-7.4.4.so -> libbaccats-stub-7.4.4.so.BAD
```

and if I compress `libbaccats-stub-9.0.6.so` with `gzip` instead then `ldconfig` complains

> ldconfig: /usr/lib64/libbaccats-stub-9.0.6.so.gz is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

and leaves my `libbaccats-7.4.4.so` symlink alone.

So while I haven't found a way to make `ldconfig` create the correct symlink, there's at least a way to prevent it from recreating the wrong one: delete, compress or otherwise mangle the file `/usr/lib64/libbaccats-stub-9.0.6.so`.

Of course the *real* solution would be to set the `SONAME` field in `libbaccats-stub-9.0.6.so` correctly, but that would have to happen in the build process of the `bacula-director` package.